# WITSML api library for .Net / C# client apps?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, api

Witsml is an xml data and query standard used in the oil and gas drilling industry. It uses xml for both the data and the query templates when communicating with a server (over http). It's a bit of a mess to manually construct queries in xml, especially since the templates specify both what elements to return *and* how to filter them.

I'm aware of some .net libraries that ease the client side of working with witsml (ie, by abstracting out the api into more of a object structure), but am curious if anyone has real-world experience working with these libraries and how well they perform. Any recommendations for what to use when building a .net application that needs to interact with a remote witsml server?

UPDATE
Adding links to the c# libraries I have found in existence:

http://nwitsml.org

http://setiri.com/witsml

http://sourceforge.net/projects/stdsdevkit/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will answer my own question with my findings:

-NWitsml.org - open source, read-only access to witsml servers. 1.2 to 1.4 compatible. Based on java code from the Jwitsml project.

-Standards DevKit - Read and Write access to witsml servers 1.3.1 and 1.4.1 compatible. Does "dumb" serialization/deserialization of witsml queries and docs, ie no state tracking or understanding of what the query contains, so the operator must know the spec well enough to create the correct query. Open source.

-Setiri.Witsml SDK - Read and Write access to witsml servers version 1.3.1 (1.4.1 compat in the works). Entities track their state and include a lot of witsml knowledge, so the user is not required to be a guru, thus a more developed/mature product. Developer seat license.

Comment: Just a note: I did a small project with the DevKit, and I found it unsuitable for creating/receiving queries. A query can (sometimes has to) omit tags that are required by the XSD. I did use it to build the response from the queries.

Comment: Henk, that is correct, it simple gives you a document and expects you to figure out how to structure the queries.

Comment: boomhauer, do you have an email I can contact you at? I've got some questions regarding nWitsml. My email is in my profile.

Comment: @jr3 I'm only a year late on this- let me know if you still would like to get in touch, I don't see your email on your profile. you can reach mea at my user name at gmail

Comment: @BradyMoritz Is there a chance we can have a conversation about WITSML, I am really interested in this field and I will appreciate your help in the same.

Comment: I'm adding my email to my profile so y'all can reach me there. thanks